# Dynamically loading polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [goMap Library](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/index.php) and have a local database with countries coordinates , It works well if I put coordinates directly into code but with click event I am calling below method to update map dynamically:

```
    $.getJSON('countries/name', function(data) {
    $.each(data.cords, function (i, v) {
    var cor = '';
        for (i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
            cor += "{longitude: "+v[i].longitude+",latitude: "+v[i].latitude+"},";
        }   
    console.log(cor);
            $.goMap.createPolygon({
                color: "#00CC00",
                fillColor: '#00CC00',
                fillOpacity:    0.2,
                weight:     2,
                coords: [cor]
            });
    });
    });
```

I want to fill `coords: [cor]` with longitude and latitude for selected country and update map, If I give values manually for `coords:  [cor]` it works well, there is no error in console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Coords` *must* be an array of `{ latitude, longitude }` not a concatenated string :

```
var cor = [];
for (i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
   cor.push({
     longitude: v[i].longitude,
     latitude: v[i].latitude
   })
}
```

and

```
coords: cor //not coords : [cor]
```

in fact, it seems to me - but cannot be 100% sure, dont know exactly what it is - that you can use `data.cords` right away. It comes clear if you inspect the [**gomap source**](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/js/jquery.gomap-1.3.3.js), `createOverlay` about line 463 :

```
case 'polygon':
    if (poly.coords.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0, l = poly.coords.length; j < l; j++)
            overlay.push(new google.maps.LatLng(poly.coords[j].latitude, poly.coords[j].longitude));

        overlay = new google.maps.Polygon({
            map: this.map,
            path: overlay,
            strokeColor: poly.color ? poly.color : this.opts.polygon.color,
            strokeOpacity: poly.opacity ? poly.opacity : this.opts.polygon.opacity,
            strokeWeight: poly.weight ? poly.weight : this.opts.polygon.weight,
            fillColor: poly.fillColor ? poly.fillColor : this.opts.polygon.fillColor,
            fillOpacity: poly.fillOpacity ? poly.fillOpacity : this.opts.polygon.fillOpacity
        });
    }
        else
            return false;
    break;
```

Why use gomap in the first place? Doesnt seem to add anything or make anything easier, just another google map v3 wrapper.

Comment: Thank you after adding array it works, I have a theme which is fully functional with goMap library